# iOS error read memory failed

Tags: ios, csv, memory, singleton

I'm working on an iPad app.

When the app is launched, user have to enter a number. With this id, I check in a csv file to get informations about the user.

Informations are saved with a singleton. This singleton is causing me problems :

step 1 : initialization of my singleton

```
+(ASMagasin*) sharedInstance {    
    if (myMagasin == nil){
        myMagasin = [[ASMagasin alloc]init];
    }
    return myMagasin;
}
```

step 2 : I call my function which work with the csv file

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSError * error;

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString * num_magasin = [defaults objectForKey:kUserDefautNumMagasin];
        [self loadMagFromCsv:filePathCsv withMagasin:num_magasin];
    }
    return self;
}
```

step 3 :

```
-(void)loadMagFromCsv:(NSString *)filePath withMagasin:(NSString *) num_magasin
{
    NSError *error;

    NSString *csvData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    NSArray *gcRawData = [csvData componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    NSArray *singleGC = [NSArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < gcRawData.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *nextGCString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", gcRawData[i]];
        singleGC = [nextGCString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        if ([singleGC[0]isEqualToString:num_magasin]){

            _num=singleGC[0];
            _libelle=singleGC[1];
            _client_defaut_nom=singleGC[2];
            _client_defaut_prenom=singleGC[3];
            _client_defaut_tel=singleGC[4];
            _client_defaut_mail=singleGC[5];

            _cp=singleGC[6];
            _ville=singleGC[7];
            _pays=singleGC[8];

        }
    }
}
```

In this function, my variable error have this value before I initialize it :

> (NSError *) error = 0x0000000000000001 domain: read memory from 0x19
>   failed (0 of 8 bytes read) - code: read memory from 0x11 failed (0 of
>   8 bytes read)

I don't know how to solve that and where is this error come from.

[image: debug]

Comment: What do you mean "before you initialise it"? - The value of a variable before you initialise in objective C it will be nil.

Comment: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/31/1406713777-capture-d-ecran-2014-07-30-a-11-43-47.png
after this error is initialized to nil

Comment: First of all you are not creating a singleton properly.

Comment: whats wrong with my singleton?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at random memory in the heap. It is meaningless. Your `NSError` hasn't even been initialised at this point, let alone assigned a value.

You can (and should) check `error` for a value after you execute the line

```
NSString *csvData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Before that `error` doesn't have a useful value.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting it with a hope that it might help others facing same issue. Not sure about its exact cause, but I was experiencing it on a variable with _block before it. Removing _block fixed this issue and didn't give any warning either. Not sure what is going on here as I experienced it after updating to iOS 14. Will update if i find anything more interesting.